# Адаптивный фон изображения на всю ширину

Tags: html, css

Все привет, мне нужно, чтоб картинка была на всю ширину, а ГЛАВНОЕ, чтоб **масштабировалось** как [тут](http://sailingcollective.com/).

Вот решение это задачи используя body: `body{background: url(background-photo.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed; 
}`
Мне нужно тоже самое только используя div. Чтоб можно было фон сайту сделать и вставлять вот такие блоки в любое место на сайте.

Comment: div {background: url(background-photo.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed; 
}

Comment: К сожалению, это абсолютно не работает

Comment: добавите для div - min-height: 100vh;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header,
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.bg {
  background: url(https://www.visitportugal.com/sites/www.visitportugal.com/files/mediateca/23_660x371.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed / cover;
}
```

```html
<header class="bg"></header>
<section></section>
<section class="bg"></section>
```

Comment: Отлично, всё работает. Если кому-то не нужна позиция "fixed", вместо неё можете использовать "local".